# How to retrieve only certain data from Parse?

Tags: parse-platform, storage

I am working with parse to save user data. I am saving every user that signs up in a parse table. I can run my app and see data from all the users who signed up; but I dont want that. What I want is to display information only from users in a friends list. Thats my problem. Should I create and query through a list of user ids or emails that I save internally in the device as JSON or raw data to upload in a new class in parse? Should I save these friend contacts directly in my current ALL USERS Parse table and get the data somehow without having the entire parse table provide all users data? I hope this makes sense to anyone. Any guidance would be really helpful. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I would suggest adding a new field to the `_User` table called `friends` as a `Relation` type and then when a user adds a new friend you can add their object ID to the `friends` `Relation` of the current user.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I ended up doing is saving the data objects in the Shared prefs. Then simply looped through the objects in the parse table and retrieved only data that matched the user id from shared prefs. This however helped me figure it out. Thanks